# Spring Security multiple login filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two different login flows in my Spring Boot app.

1. Normal form login
2. Stateless login

I tried the following, but it always coming to 2nd one filter. How do I restrict `/api/**` to fall for stateless authentication and others to normal session form login?

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");
    } 

    private final UserService userService;

    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public WebSecurityConfig() {
         super(true);
         this.userService = new UserService();
         tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets", userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
             .csrf().disable();

         // Normal form login using jdbc
         http
             .authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                 .and()
             .formLogin()
                 .loginPage("/login")
                 .usernameParameter("username")
                 .passwordParameter("password")
                 .permitAll()
                 .and()
             .logout().permitAll();
         //Stateless authentication using tokens - Custome authentication from token implemented in the filter
         http
             .authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers("/api").authenticated()
                 .and()
             .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
             UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overall, spring security handles this by using multiple HTTP blocks.

You'll need to nest multiple configurations - this is how Java configuration handles this. Importantly, these configurations need the "Order" annotation to make sure spring loads them in the right order - configurations for specific sub-paths (such as API) must be loaded before the configuration which includes "/".

So your example would become something similar to this (more rearranging could make it simpler, just demonstrating the split):

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private final UserService userService;

    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public WebSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
        this.userService = new UserService();
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets", userService);
    }

    @Order(0)
    @Configuration
    private final class ApiSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable();

            //Stateless authentication using tokens - Custome authentication from token implemented in the filter
            http.antMatchers("/api").authorizeRequests()
               .authenticated().and()
               .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
             UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
             .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
             .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");
    } 
    }

     @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
     @Configuration
     private final class OtherSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable();

            //Normal form login using jdbc
            http.antMatchers("/", "/home").authorizeRequests().access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
               .loginPage("/login") .usernameParameter("username")
               .passwordParameter("password").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
             .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
             .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");
        } 
    }
}
```